# Deleting specific rows of CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file, and i want to delete some rows of it based on the values of one of the columns. I do not know the related code to delete the specific rows of a CSV file which is in type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

I read related questions, and i found that people suggest writing every line that is acceptable in a new file. I do not want to do that. The thing that i want is:

1) to delete the rows that I know the index of them (number of the row)

or

2) to make a new CSV in the memory of the python (not to write and again read it )

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like and what you want it to look like after your manipulations? A few rows (~5) is sufficient.

Comment: thanks, added to the body of the question.

Comment: I assume you mean time is bigger than or equal to 22:05 ? Otherwise the first row of your output would be dropped.

Comment: yes. I just want the rows that its time is bigger than a threshold, like 22:05. I know how to detect them, I don't know how to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do with `pandas`. If you need more detail, you might find [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) a helpful resource.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""speed,time,date
12,22:05,1
15,22:10,1
13,22:15,1""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr)

# convert time column to timedelta, assuming mm:ss
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['time'])

# filter for >= 22:10, i.e. second item
df = df[df['time'] >= df['time'].loc[1]]

print(df)

   speed     time  date
1     15 00:22:10     1
2     13 00:22:15     1
```

Comment: very good, thank you. It is very nice of you if you can let me know how to add data to mysrt in a loop.  I mean, in a loop I detect which rows are acceptable.  now, I want to add the acceptable data to mystr at that loop.

Comment: @ReihanehKouhi, Assume there is no `mystr`, this is a placeholder for my comment `# replace mystr with 'file.csv'`.